# «Ошибка последовательности функций» в SQL-запросе для добавления данных

Tags: sql, qt

Лог ошибки.

```
INSERT INTO  Delivery_statistics (Номенклатура товара, Кол-во, Цена,Дата) VALUES('Карандаш', 111, 15,#01/01/2017#)"
    QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Ошибка последовательности функций"
    "[Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Ошибка последовательности функций"
    "QODBC3: Unable to execute statement"`
```

Код

```
  QSqlQuery Query;
  QString QueryStr = "INSERT INTO  "+nameTable+" (Номенклатура товара, Кол-во, Цена,Дата) VALUES('Карандаш', 111, 15,#01/01/2017#)";

  qDebug()<<QueryStr;
  Query.prepare(QueryStr);
  if(!Query.exec())
    {
      qDebug()<<Query.lastError().databaseText();
      qDebug()<<Query.lastError().driverText();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это Access, попробуйте так:

```
QString QueryStr = "INSERT INTO  "+nameTable+" ([Номенклатура товара], [Кол-во], Цена,Дата) VALUES('Карандаш', 111, 15,#01/01/2017#)";
```

Comment: Спасибо дружище!
Можешь растолковать на пальцах с чем связанна обрамление квадратными скобками параметров [Номенклатура товара] и [Кол-во] c  номенклатурой вероятно из за этого что это (массив = строка) но почему параметр кол-во нуждается в скобках ?

Comment: Требуется, если имя содержит недопустимые символы, например: пробел, дефис.

Comment: А как это исправить ?!
"[Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Ошибка последовательности функций"
"QODBC3: Unable to execute statement"
"INSERT INTO  Delivery_statistics ([Номенклатура товара], [Кол-во], Цена,Дата,[Клиент]) VALUES('Авторучка',100,100,#05/01/2017#,'ТОО СтройТоргВсе'"

Comment: Вероятно проблема в параметре 'ТОО СтройТоргВсе' ... 
Тут нужно как то экранировать его ?!

Comment: Если это весь запрос, то нет закрывающей скобки.

Answer (score 0):

Последний параметр должен быть в кавычках

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]