# Ещё одна «Ошибка последовательности функций» при добавлении данных

Tags: sql, qt

*[Вчерашняя ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/670386/208074) (неверно принимаемая за вопрос-дубликат) была решена путём заключения имён полей в квадратные скобки ([спасибо @msi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670403/208074)). Однако сразу же после этого возникла ещё одна ошибка, описанная ниже.*

Вероятно проблема в параметре 'ТОО СтройТоргВсе' ...

Тут нужно как то экранировать его ?!

Лог ошибки.

```
QODBCResult::exec: Unable to execute statement: "[Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Ошибка последовательности функций"
"[Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Ошибка последовательности функций"
"QODBC3: Unable to execute statement"
"INSERT INTO  Delivery_statistics ([Номенклатура товара], [Кол-во],Цена,Дата,Клиент) VALUES('Авторучка',150,10,#05/01/2017#,'ТОО СтройТоргВсе'"
```

Код

```
  QSqlQuery Query;
  QString QueryStr = "INSERT INTO  "+nameTable.toString()+
                     " ([Номенклатура товара], [Кол-во],Цена,Дата,Клиент) VALUES('"
                      +item.toString()+"',"+count.toString()+","+cost.toString()+",#"
                      +date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy")+"#,'"+Client.toString()+"'";

  Query.prepare(QueryStr);
  if(!Query.exec())
    {
      qDebug()<<Query.lastError().databaseText();
      qDebug()<<Query.lastError().driverText();
      qDebug()<<Query.lastQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Как минимум, у вас отсутствует закрывающаяся скобка в конце после `Client.toString()`.

Comment: `'ТОО СтройТоргВсе')` <- должно быть так, проверьте снова.

Comment: А причем тут MySQL ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка в запросе SQL добавление данных .(QT)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/670386/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-sql-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-qt)

Comment: Ошибки похожи но разные ...